# Mongoose populate how to get populate document in same object instead of sub document

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am using mongoose populate for getting another documents.I am getting data but as sub document instead of sub document how can i get in same object.

```
{
"key":"value"
"userid":{
_id:"userid"
}
}
```

but i need to get like below

{
"key":"value"
"userid":"userid"
}

Answer (score 0):

You could change the properties of your scheme.

it:

```
 "userid":{
   type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: "User"
 }
```

intead:

```
"userid":{
 id:{
 type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
 ref: "User"
 }
}
```

Comment: actually ref document i am getting as sub document instead of that i want to get as same level of document response